# Java Login Form somehow skips if-else statement

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to create a Login and Register form using Java and SQL Workbench. The Register form works properly as the Username and Password are added to the SQL Database. As for the Login form, everything looks fine. But, when it is executed, it skips the If Statement and goes straight to the Else Statement. The Username and Password are correct as I checked the SQL Database table. The output is a SqlSyntaxErrorException. Therefore, I think my syntax is wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated!

This is the code below:

```
if (e.getSource() == LOG_IN_BUTTON)
    {

        String userName = USER_NAME_TEXTFIELD.getText();
        String password = PASSWORD_TEXTFIELD.getText();

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airline_connect",
                    "root", "Yasser1595");

            String sql = "Select user_name, password from account where user_name=? and password=?";

            st = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            st.setString(1, userName);
            st.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            if (rs.next()) {
                frame.dispose();
                new MainGame();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LOG_IN_BUTTON, "You have successfully logged in");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LOG_IN_BUTTON, "Wrong Username & Password");
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you check the stack trace/message of the exception. It should contain more information about what's wrong with your syntax.

Comment: @magicmn java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and password=?' at line 1

Comment: @magicmn This is the error, I know it is a Syntax Error, and something is wrong with the Syntax but I don't know how to solve this issue. And where is "Line 1"?

Comment: Note that you should _never_ store passwords in a database for login; instead, you should hash them (using a login-specific hash like BCrypt) and compare them. More generally, in real applications you should always use tested libraries to do this job, but this seems to be for your own learning.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Oh, ok. Thanks! I will look more into that.

Comment: You have passed sql query in executeQuery() method; although you are using PrepareStatement. Try after removing sql from executeQuery().

Comment: @VikasDubey Thanks for the reply, I tried this but it still doesn't work. It goes straight to the Else Block.

Comment: @RuntimeTerror Your query syntax is correct and what only I can see that unexpected sql in executeQuery(). If **else** part is executing that means your resultset is empty. Please check you table for that particular record and also check for leading an trailing space in your table if record exist.

Comment: My table is correct, the username and password are correct. But, I didn’t check for trailing space, I’ll check that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not use `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` but the parent's `Statement.executeQuery(sql)` which is a known pitfall. Also it is worth using try-with-resources with local variables. Not closing things can cause resource leaks.

```
   String sql = "select user_name, password from account where user_name=? and password=?";
   try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airline_connect",
                "root", "Yasser1595");
            PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        st.setString(1, userName);
        st.setString(2, password);
        try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) { // No sql parameter.
            if (rs.next()) {
                frame.dispose();
                new MainGame();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LOG_IN_BUTTON, "You have successfully logged in");
                return;
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LOG_IN_BUTTON, "Wrong Username & Password");
        }
    } catch (SQLException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

***It still did not work***

- PASSWORD also is a function, but as no syntax errors happend, that probably is no problem. You might try `"password"` (= column name).
- The column might store not the password - which is a security risk, should
  the database be stolen in the future. It might store some hash of the    password.

So:

```
String sql = "SELECT user_name, \"password\" "
    + "FROM account "
    + "WHERE user_name=? AND \"password\"=PASSWORD(?)";
```

First check how passwords (or their hashes) are stored.

It might also be the case that the password handling is done at the java side, for instance by taking the MD5 of the password and storing that.

Should all work, consider an other securite measure: if the password field is a JPasswordField one should ideally not work with a `String`, but a `char[]` that can be wiped out after usage (`Arrays.setAll(pwdArray, ' ');`). A `String` could reside long in memory, which might be a security risk.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it still doesn't work. It still goes straight to the Else Block.

Comment: As passwords normally are treated somewhat circumstantially, that could pose a problem. You might do `SELECT user_name, password FROM account` to see what is stored. It also might be you tested with a special char password, that gets the wrong encoding. I extended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Don't pass the sql string to `executeQuery`. When you pass the sql string to `executeQuery` it considers it as plain text instead of prepared statement

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still doesn't work. It still goes straight to the Else Statement.

Comment: Earlier it was going the catch block due to Syntax error. But now it’s going to else block?

Comment: Yes, I’m very confused.

Comment: Inspect the values of username and password which enters the code via debugging or logging and verify if it’s correct. Also check if there are any additional spaces in the inputs

Comment: Ok, I will check that. Thank you!